# Does Enlarge Person stack with Expansion

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, psionics, creature-size

Do the Psionic Power "Expansion" stack with the Arcane Spell "Enlarge Person"?
The Expansion power reads:

> This power causes instant growth, doubling your height, length, and width and multiplying your weight by 8. This increase changes your size category to the next larger one. You gain a +2 size bonus to Strength, a -2 size penalty to Dexterity (to a minimum effective Dexterity score of 1), a -1 size penalty on attack rolls, and a -1 size penalty to Armor Class due to your increased size.
>
> If your new size is Large or larger, you have a space of at least 10 feet and a natural reach of at least 10 feet. This power doesn’t change your speed. If insufficient room is available for the desired growth, you attain the maximum possible size and can make a Strength check (using your increased Strength score) to burst any enclosures in the process. If you fail, you are constrained without harm by the materials enclosing you—you cannot crush yourself to death by increasing your size.
>
> All your equipment, worn or carried, is similarly expanded by this power. Melee and projectile weapons deal more damage.
>
> Other psionic or magical properties are not affected by this power. Any affected item that leaves your possession (including a projectile or thrown weapon) instantly returns to its normal size. This means that thrown weapons deal their normal damage (projectiles deal damage based on the size of the weapon that fired them). Multiple effects that increase size do not stack, which means (among other things) that you can’t use a second manifestation of this power to further expand yourself.
>
> Augment
>   You can augment this power in one or more of the following ways.
>
> If you spend 6 additional power points, this power increases your size by two size categories instead of one. You gain a +4 size bonus to Strength, a -4 size penalty to Dexterity (to a minimum effective Dexterity score of 1), a -2 size penalty on attack rolls, and a -2 size penalty to Armor Class due to your increased size.
>   If you spend 6 additional power points, you can manifest this power as a swift action instead of a standard action.
>   If you spend 2 additional power points, this power’s duration is 10 minutes per level rather than 1 round per level.

The Enlarge Person spell reads:

> This spell causes instant growth of a humanoid creature, doubling its height and multiplying its weight by 8. This increase changes the creature’s size category to the next larger one. The target gains a +2 size bonus to Strength, a -2 size penalty to Dexterity (to a minimum of 1), and a -1 penalty on attack rolls and AC due to its increased size.
>
> A humanoid creature whose size increases to Large has a space of 10 feet and a natural reach of 10 feet. This spell does not change the target’s speed.
>
> If insufficient room is available for the desired growth, the creature attains the maximum possible size and may make a Strength check (using its increased Strength) to burst any enclosures in the process. If it fails, it is constrained without harm by the materials enclosing it— the spell cannot be used to crush a creature by increasing its size.
>
> All equipment worn or carried by a creature is similarly enlarged by the spell. Melee and projectile weapons affected by this spell deal more damage. Other magical properties are not affected by this spell. Any enlarged item that leaves an enlarged creature’s possession (including a projectile or thrown weapon) instantly returns to its normal size. This means that thrown weapons deal their normal damage, and projectiles deal damage based on the size of the weapon that fired them. Magical properties of enlarged items are not increased by this spell.
>
> Multiple magical effects that increase size do not stack,.
>
> Enlarge person counters and dispels reduce person.
>
> Enlarge person can be made permanent with a permanency spell.

The most important part of this is that Enlarge Person clearly states that it does not stack with other magical effects that increase size. However, Expansion is a Psionic effect instead of a magical effect. Would this mean that these two effects stack?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the description of *Expansion*:

> Multiple effects that increase size do not stack, which means (among other things) that you can’t use a second manifestation of this power to further expand yourself.

So, the answer is no.

As mentioned by @HeyICanChan, it is also important to note that in D&D 3.5 the Psionic Powers come with the [Psionics-Magic Transparency](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicPowersOverview.htm#psionicsMagicTransparency) rule. And therefore:

> Multiple magical effects that increase size do not stack.

Applies to *Expansion* as well.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: I hesitated adding the psionics-magic transparency rule, but I have heard that some tables played without... is it official and recommended or just optional?

Comment: [They're the default rules.](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/psionicPowersOverview.htm#psionicsMagicTransparency) And, by way of personal experience, I've never played in a psionics-are-different campaign, everyone agreeing beforehand that making a distinction between the two made things excessively complicated. (I know that some *AD&D 2E* settings default instead to psionics–magic opacity (like the Forgotten Realms), but in *3E* the standard is psionics is magic. @KRyan knows this psionics stuff better than I, though.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan: Thanks, I have added a blurb about the psionics-magic transparency rule directly in the answer.

Comment: Is it worth also trying to describe what happens under magic-psi indices opacity?

Comment: @fectin: The clause in *Expansion* is agnostic of the origin of the potential other effects increasing size, so it covers both the transparency and opacity case. Transparency only effects the clause in *Enlarge Person*, which is only used to corroborate here, and is not necessary.

Comment: Just for the record, all 2E had magic and psionics as separate by default.  The Complete Psionics Handbook says that they are different, and has specific powers in the Metapsionic discipline for detecting and effecting magic.